# Fat Free PHP Layouts

Tags: php, templates, fat-free-framework

I'm going through some of the code and projects provided here http://fatfreeframework.com/development.  My goal is to create a lightweight MVC kickstarter projecting using F3.  I know it's been done before, but I'm using this as a learning exercise and I hope to have something useful come out of it in the end.

The biggest stumbling block I'm coming across right now is the concept of layouts.  I know the documentation mentions using templates within templates, but I'm struggling to implement it in practice.   In the end, I want to have 1 or 2 layouts (default layout, maybe a custom one for modal popups, etc), and then have my views rendered wrapped inside of those layouts.  I want a default layout and then the ability to override the default for the few pages that need custom ones.  Here's the code I've been using:

```
// this is the handler for one of my routes, it's on a controller class called Index
public function index($f3, $params) 
{
    // this (or anything else) should get passed into the view
    $f3->set('listOfItems',array("item1", "item2"));

    // set the view
    $f3->set('content', 'index.htm')

    // render the layout
    \Template::instance()->render('layout.htm');
}
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting a blank page.  Am I going about this completely the wrong direction, or am I on the right track?  Is there a way to set a default layout somewhere so it's used until it's overridden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you could create a base class with a default layout. Then you extend it for each controller class. For example:

```
abstract class Layout {

  protected $tpl='layout.htm';

  function afterRoute($f3,$params) {
    echo \Template::instance()->render($this->tpl);
  }

}
```

Then:

```
class OneController extends Layout {

  function index($f3,$params) {
    $f3->set('listOfItems',...);
    $f3->set('content','one/index.htm');
  }

}

class AnotherController extends Layout {

  protected $tpl='popup.htm';//override default layout here

  function index($f3,$params) {
    $f3->set('listOfItems',...);
    $f3->set('content','another/index.htm');
  }

}
```

In layout.htm:

```
<body>
  <div id="content">
    <include href="{{@content}}" if="isset(@content)"/>
  </div>
</body>
```

Structure of the `UI` folder:

```
/ui
  |-- layout.htm
  |-- popup.htm
  |-- one
        |-- index.htm
  |-- another
        |-- index.htm
```

This is just one example of how you could organize your code. F3 is loose enough to let you organize it in a multitude of ways.

Comment: Interesting, I'll see how this works.  I assume that if I needed to supply any data to the another/index.htm or one/index.htm "sublayouts" I could do that with the standard $f3 set method and it'll pick it up? I think I remember reading that the set() method is global so does that mean that both the template AND the subtemplate would be able to see that var...

Comment: Yes exactly, these are global variables. For small projects that makes things quick and easy. For larger projects though, you might consider managing a local set of variables inside the `Layout` class and then pass it to the `Template->render` function.

Comment: This posted helped me understand what F3 calls certain things in regards to its MVC translation.  In my world, the layout is a "template" and is rendered by \Template::instance()->render, while the "view" is set by the $f3->set('content', 'some markup') call.

Comment: when including the views by using <include href={{@content... are the included views supposed to allow stuff like <?php echo "test" ?> in it, or are we limited to F3's template language?

Comment: Instead of using the include for this,  bet I could run \View::instance()->render('views/index/index.phtml'); and set that to the content variable...

Comment: I tried this, but I had to render it with | raw after it, and I'm sure that's a security risk...

Comment: if I change the view from .html to .php, it processes the PHP, but my layout still seems to be ignoring any PHP code inside of it.

Comment: `<include>` expects a F3-style template, that's correct. Any `<?php ...?>` will be ignored. If you want to include a PHP template, then use `{{ \View::instance()->render('path/index.phtml') }}`. The file extension (`.html`, `.php` or `.anything`) is not important.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem - set everything up as required, rendered the layout, and kept getting a blank page.  Also when I checked the HTML source of the rendered page it was completely empty.

If you look closely however rendering the layout is not enough, you have to also *print* it using the `echo` command.  So rather than the following example which appears at first glance to be correct:

```
$f3->route('GET /',
    function($f3) {

        // Instantiates a View object
        $view = new View;

        // Render the page
        $view->render('template/layout.php');
```

you actually need the last line to start with `echo`:

```
        echo $view->render('template/layout.php');
```

For more examples see:

- http://fatfreeframework.com/views-and-templates
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-fat-free-php-framework
- http://takacsmark.com/fat-free-php-framework-tutorial-4-database-models-crud/

Also for some reason (which I'm sure will become clear soon - I've only just started using the Fat Free Framework) you seem to also be able to render an `.htm` file which contain embedded PHP (i.e. they don't have to have the `.php` extension).